# Using geom_text & facet_wrap: Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am experiencing this weird error..

Some test data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

test <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("G", "N", "P"), class = "factor"), 
        var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
        1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), 
        group2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
        2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
        3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("O", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
        cor = c(0.270075198428616, 0.262097140096646, -0.331312784846655, 
        -0.343984945812309, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), .Names = c("group", "var", 
    "group2", "cor"), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to make this plot:

```
test %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=group2, y=cor)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=var, group=var)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(cor,2),
                vjust = ifelse(cor >= 0, 0, 1),
                group=var),
            position = position_dodge(width=1)) +
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales="free_x")
```

.. which results in: `Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`

However, without `geom_text` it works:
[image]

And also only using rows 1:40 works:

```
test %>% slice(1:40) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=group2, y=cor)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=var, group=var)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(cor,2),
                vjust = ifelse(cor >= 0, 0, 1),
                group=var),
            position = position_dodge(width=1)) +
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

So up to row 40 there are only two levels for `group`, and from row 41 on there is a third level. But how can that cause this error? Or is there something else I don't see?

Comment: Which packages do you use?

Comment: @Pascal sorry, edited, I use `dplyr` and `ggplot2` for this

Comment: Is there a reason you're using this data-structure? Unusual to have so many missings in your outcome variabe which seems aggregated.

Comment: @Heroka I did fill the dataframe with NAs as to avoid the problem of differing bar widths...

Comment: Is my answer below of any help?

Comment: @RHA thanks for your answer, I had no time to test it yet, but will do next week and give feedback then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error also disappears if you erase `facet_wrap` or if not all of your P-group is NA (for example change the last entry for cor in 0.2). So apparently, if a facet is empty (contains only NA's), `geom_text` can't handle that.

If you really want to include the empty facet, here's a workaround:
1. replace at least 1 (or all?) NA's in the empty facets with a 0. The bar will have 0 length, so no problem there
2. Now you have a zero label in your graph. By using `alpha=ifelse(cor == 0, 0, 1)` you'll make that label fully transparent.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
test <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("G", "N", "P"), class = "factor"), 
                       var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), 
                       group2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                            2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
                                            3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                            4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("O", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
                       cor = c(0.270075198428616, 0.262097140096646, -0.331312784846655, 
                               -0.343984945812309, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                               0)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), .Names = c("group", "var", 
                                                                         "group2", "cor"), class = "data.frame")


test %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=group2, y=cor)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=var, group=var)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(cor,2),
                vjust = ifelse(cor >= 0, 0, 1),
                group=var, alpha=ifelse(cor == 0, 0, 1)),
            position = position_dodge(width=1)) +
  theme_bw(base_size=18) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

If you want to remove the legend of geom_text, simply add `show_guide  = FALSE`.

EDIT: If the transparency doesn't work right, @beetroot came up with this nice alternative: replace `alpha=ifelse(cor == 0, 0, 1)` with `size=ifelse(cor == 0, NA, 3))`

Comment: Thanks, I was finally able to test. Unfortunately I see the 0 labels (they have about the colour of the grid lines though), any idea what the problem might be there?

Comment: @beetroot. I have no idea. With alpha=0 they should be fully transparent. Do you see them in R/Rstudio or on an export (png/pdf)?

Comment: in both RStudio and the exported file. However, your answer gave me the idea to play with that a bit and I tried with size instead of alpha `size=ifelse(cor == 0, NA, 3))` and it works now...

Comment: @beetroot: nice alternative! I will add that to my answer, it that's all right (with reference to you off course!).